# Different markers in MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm using this generated code to plot a psychometric function between two vectors:

```
smqi=[0 0.504500000000000   0.540500000000000   0.574800000000000   0.459400000000000   0.500800000000000   0.533900000000000   0.401700000000000   0.462100000000000   0.511300000000000   0.291300000000000   0.347300000000000   0.419900000000000   0.491700000000000   0.552400000000000   0.598600000000000   0.392600000000000   0.426000000000000   0.451400000000000   0.334900000000000   0.359500000000000   0.371300000000000   0   0.640800000000000   0.760600000000000   0.847100000000000   0.336200000000000   0.409200000000000   0.463000000000000   0.357600000000000   0.437700000000000   0.504400000000000   0.421200000000000   0.500200000000000   0.579800000000000   0.452700000000000   0.557200000000000   0.592200000000000   0.314800000000000   0.313800000000000   0.344800000000000   0.315500000000000   0.348300000000000   0.355400000000000   0   0.558100000000000   0.636700000000000   0.702900000000000   0.361500000000000   0.427100000000000   0.469100000000000   0.389700000000000   0.457700000000000   0.489800000000000   0.446800000000000   0.528700000000000   0.589200000000000   0.441500000000000   0.475300000000000   0.499600000000000   0.325500000000000   0.360700000000000   0.364200000000000   0.338400000000000   0.368200000000000   0.396200000000000   0   0.702500000000000   0.813100000000000   0.995500000000000   0.370600000000000   0.476800000000000   0.594300000000000   0.355200000000000   0.452000000000000   0.528500000000000   0.484000000000000   0.567400000000000   0.671500000000000   0.454000000000000   0.460700000000000   0.469600000000000   0.299900000000000   0.318300000000000   0.361900000000000   0.264800000000000   0.263000000000000   0.279500000000000];
MOS=[0.240085000000000  0.558541000000000   0.861963000000000   0.935125000000000   0.276903000000000   0.634308000000000   0.838878000000000   0.268853000000000   0.274772000000000   0.724518000000000   0.285545000000000   0.238901000000000   0.477684000000000   0.338700000000000   0.655736000000000   0.656328000000000   0.138511000000000   0.388422000000000   0.582929000000000   0.368178000000000   0.364626000000000   0.341423000000000   0.237362000000000   0.728069000000000   0.894282000000000   1   0.348526000000000   0.689712000000000   0.712087000000000   0.473541000000000   0.558778000000000   0.600331000000000   0.480052000000000   0.638688000000000   0.924944000000000   0.349947000000000   0.765834000000000   0.826684000000000   0.279507000000000   0.315852000000000   0.529892000000000   0.193678000000000   0.282112000000000   0.375873000000000   0.266012000000000   0.536285000000000   0.739079000000000   0.924825000000000   0.362969000000000   0.516160000000000   0.724162000000000   0.417663000000000   0.649461000000000   0.682846000000000   0.540784000000000   0.823606000000000   0.900438000000000   0.277850000000000   0.318693000000000   0.433763000000000   0.221617000000000   0.281165000000000   0.381674000000000   0.141352000000000   0.335740000000000   0.391263000000000   0   0.659879000000000   0.834853000000000   0.953475000000000   0.502664000000000   0.609921000000000   0.818042000000000   0.402155000000000   0.543270000000000   0.755890000000000   0.470700000000000   0.621996000000000   0.748905000000000   0.375873000000000   0.501243000000000   0.682254000000000   0.126080000000000   0.294779000000000   0.353972000000000   0.223748000000000   0.369599000000000   0.261276000000000];
function [fitresult, gof] = createFit(smqi, mos)
%CREATEFIT(SMQI,MOS)
%  Create a fit.
%
%  Data for 'untitled fit 1' fit:
%      X Input : smqi 1x88
%      Y Output: mos  1x88
%  Output:
%      fitresult : a fit object representing the fit.

[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData(smqi, mos);

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype( 'erfc((a+b*x)/sqrt(2))/2', 'independent', 'x', 'dependent', 'y' );
opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares' );
opts.Algorithm = 'Levenberg-Marquardt';
opts.Display = 'Off';
opts.StartPoint = [0.83763959965349 0.463660782983039];

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );


% Plot fit with data.
figure( 'Name', 'untitled fit 1' );
h = plot( fitresult, xData, yData );
legend( h, 'mos vs. smqi', 'untitled fit 1', 'Location', 'NorthEast' );
% Label axes
xlabel smqi
ylabel mos
grid on
```

I want to specify different markers for each group of 22 values of the vectors SMQI and MOS while preserving the same line (`fitresult`).
I looked after the scatter function but I didn't succeed into solving this issue.

Help?

Comment: please include your data.

Comment: my data are just float values. I must include 88 values for each vectors ? (the code works well, but i just want to put markers in each subvector)

Comment: It's just more likely that someone offers your answer, if you give us something to play with. I'm too lazy to think about an adequate example to reproduce your case.

Comment: ah, i did not understand that you want to reproduce it. Ok i edit my post

Comment: Do you want different markers or different colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do, would be to reshape your `xData` and `yData` variables into [X x 4] and then pass these to plot to create a separate plot object for each group. You can then set markers as desired.

```
xData = reshape(xData, [], 4);
yData = reshape(yData, [], 4);

p = plot(xData, yData, '.');
set(p, {'Marker'}, {'.'; 'o'; 'x'; '*'})

hold on
plot(fitresult);
```

Comment: thank's for you response but there is more than 4 markers in your solution. I want a marker for each 22 values since i have 88 values => 1 marker for each 22values.

Comment: but how about the "fitresult" variable. You didn't put it in the plot function ?

Comment: ah yes, i just tried it now. ok, it works well, thanks for you constructive ideas !